# Php how many three/four/five digit numbers do I have in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which has several numbers.
What I want to do is get a loop and run into this array and count how many two-digits numbers, three-digits, four-digits numbers do I have.

I also tried this:

```
$threeDigits=0;
$fourDigits=0;
$fiveDigits=0;
$sixDigits=0;

$myArray=(123,1234,12345,123456,1234567,111,222)
for($i=1,$size=count($myArray);$i<=$size;i++)
{
if(strlen($==3)) $threeDigits++;
else if(strlen($i==4)) $fourDigits++;
else if(strlen($i==5)) $fiveDigits++;
else if(strlen($i==6)) $sixDigits++;
}
echo "There are " .$fourDigits. " numbers with 4 digits.";
echo "There are " .$threeDigits. " numbers with 3 digits.";
echo "There are " .$fiveDigits. " numbers with 5 digits.";
echo "There are " .$sixDigits. " numbers with 6 digits.";
```

But somehow it only reads them as one. As you can see, in my array there are three three-digit numbers but when I print it out it says I have only one. What do you think it might be the problem here?

Comment: You have numerous syntax errors in your code and at the moment doesn't even run.

Comment: In your loop there is no variable taking the value of the current array element, $myArray[i]. I don't know what you are trying to obtain from the conditions `strlen($i==4)`. Where is the current element in that condition? For traversing all elements in an array you usually use a foreach loop https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_foreach.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any answer that "suited" my code better, I tried and solved this out.

Here's my code if someone else in the future needs it.

```
<?php
$threeDigits=0;
$fourDigits=0;
$fiveDigits=0;
$sixDigits=0;

$myArray=array(123,111,1234,12345,123456);
$size=count($myArray);

foreach($myArray as $el){
    if(strlen($el) == 3)
    {
    $threeDigits++;
    }
    else if(strlen($el)==4)
    {
        $fourDigits++;
    }
    else if(strlen($el)==5)
    {
    $fiveDigits++;
}
else if (strlen($el)==6)
{
    $sixDigits++;
}
}
echo "there are " .$threeDigits. " three digits numbers -- " ;
echo "there are " .$fourDigits. " four digits numbers -- " ;
echo "there are " .$fiveDigits. " five digits numbers -- " ;
echo "there are " .$sixDigits. " six digits numbers -- " ;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iteration over an array should be done by using `foreach` (because in PHP, arrays can have gaps in the offset keys)

```
foreach($myArray as $i => $myValue) {
    // .. do something
}
```

Secondly, you're determining the string length of `$i`, which is the key. But you want to use the value *at* the key:

```
$myArray[$i]
```

Considering the example above, `$myValue` corresponds to `$myArray[$i]`